# Смысл тестового задания

Tags: javascript

Дорогие форумчане, получил тестовое задание такого вида. Не могу понять нескольких вещей:

- конечный результат это определенное количество горизонтальных линий,
  которые состоят в свою очередь из отдельных блоков разных цветов?
- если да, то тогда зачем указывать цвет для обьектов массива lines, если он все равно будет перекрыт обьектами из elements?
- каким образом лучше реализовать апдейт цвета: отдельной функцией через setInterval? Пока нет никаких идей на этот счет

Буду рад любому ответу. Спасибо!

**Вот описание задачи:**

"Все сталкивались с профилактическим вещанием на телевизионных каналах. Вам необходимо реализовать следующую задачу.

У вас есть набор входных данных в объекте по типу:

```
var params = {

    lines: [
        {    
            background: '#00F',    
            updateTime: 1000,     
            elements: [{     
                background: '#00F',     
                width: 25     
            },    
            {     
                background: '#00F',     
                width: 50     
            },     
            {
                background: '#00F',     
                width: 25    
            },...     
          ]     
        }...     
    ]     
}
```

Реализуйте отрисовку этих данных следующим образом. Весь экран должен заполниться элементами массива lines ширина которых равна ширине экрана, а высота результату деления высоты экрана на число линий.Цвет линии должен быть взят из свойства background.

В каждой линии есть элементы параметры которых берутся из массива elements , каждый элемент должен быть отрисован с соответствующей шириной указанной в процентах, высотой равной высоте линии, и цветом из свойства background.

В зависимости от свойства updateTime в каждой строке необходимо реализовать смену цвета на любой другой цвет(необходимо реализовать генератор цвета), в интервале времени соответствующему количеству миллисекунд указанному в свойстве.

При выполнении задач не рекомендуется использование посторонних библиотек, фреймворков, также необходимо что бы примеры работали одинаково в основных браузерах Chrome, Firefox, IE9+, Opera"

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись.

Comment: "Пока нет никаких идей на этот счет" - ну, по крайней мере одна-то идея есть: "отдельной функцией через setInterval"

Comment: Такое впечатление что ТЗ составлял бухгалтер отдела сантехники который возомнил что он во всем разбирается. А так задание на час максимум, это вместе с придумыванием за чаем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо реализовать отпугиватель эпилептика))

- Да, конечный результат это определенное количество горизонтальных линий, которые состоят в свою очередь из отдельных блоков разных цветов.
- Понятия не имею, но вдруг ширина элементов будет меньше 100%? Или больше?
- Лучше реализовать апдейт цвета отдельной функцией через setInterval, которая будет проходить по массиву. Массив лучше сформировать заранее, а не лезть в DOM каждый раз.

Так как это тестовое задание, можно попробовать все это реализовать через ООП для поднятия престижа в глазах проверяющего. В общем-то вроде как все правильно понимаете, остается дело за реализацией.